# Redefine standard math environment \[ ... \]?

Tags: math-mode, align, environments

Is it possible to redefine `\[ ... \]` to be equivalent to `\begin{align} ... \end{align}`?

(I seldom use anything but the `align` environment, and `\[ ... \]` is faster and looks cleaner.)

Comment: What would be a motivation?

Comment: (@egreg: See edit.)

Comment: You shouldn't substitute `equation` with `align`, which should only be used with multiline displays.

Comment: @egreg: In this case, this new `\[ ... \]` could choose automatically...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `align` environment is special in the sense, that it needs the end tag `\end{align}` to be present and not hidden inside macros. The environment internally catches the contents of the environment. Then it can measure the widths, before setting the equations. Therefore the following redefinition only redefines `\[` and uses `\]` to limit the parameter with the contents and passes it to `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}`:

```
\def\[#1\]{%
  \begin{align}#1\end{align}%
}
```

(`\long\def` would be needed, when it can happen that there are empty lines
in the parameter `#1`. However, environment `align` does not like long arguments, thus the definition without `\long` is better here, see user66081's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321958/redefine-standard-math-environment/321960?noredirect=1#comment787260_321960).)

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\[#1\]{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}
\begin{document}
\[
  a &= b\\
  c &= d
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: It won't digest empty lines because `align` doesn't. It is better w/o `\long` because the error message (in case of empty lines) makes reference to `\[` instead of `align`

Comment: (This is great.)

Comment: @user66081 You are right, the original `\[` ... `\]` (without `amsmath`) allows empty lines, but `align` of `amsmath` does not.

Comment: Better (IMO) to define `\protected\def\[#1\]{\begin{equation*}\begin{split}#1\end{split}\end{equation*}}` (or with `aligned` rather than `split` may be.

Comment: @Manuel My interpretation of the question is that `\[`...`\]` should be just a shortcut for `\begin{align}`...`\end{align}`, because `align` is the main equation type for the document. Unnumbered equation types still remain available (`displaymath`,  `equation*`).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Yes, my mistake. The `*` should be out. What I mean is that may be he wants an equation environment in which he can align things by default (which is what should happen by default IMO) so that's a way to combine `equation` with `aligned` or with `split`.