# How to use \def to redefine \end{split}?

Tags: errors, split

When I use `\def` to redefine `\end{split}`, there is an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\def\be{\begin{equation}}
\def\ee{\end{equation}}
\def\bs{\begin{split}}
\def\es{\end{split}}

\be
    \bs
        a\\
        b
    \es
\ee

\end{document}
```

The error is:

> Runaway argument?
>
> a\ b \es \ee
>
> ! Paragraph ended before \split was complete.

However, if I don't use `\def\es{\end{split}}` and just modify the code to be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\def\be{\begin{equation}}
\def\ee{\end{equation}}
\def\bs{\begin{split}}
\def\es{\end{split}}

\be
    \bs
        a\\
        b
    \end{split}
\ee

\end{document}
```

it's OK. What's the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! The issue is the same as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321960/121799): LaTeX wants to see an explicit `\end{split}`. So you *could* use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\def\be{\begin{equation}}
\def\ee{\end{equation}}
\def\bs#1\es{\begin{split}#1\end{split}}


\be
    \bs
        a\\
        b
    \es
\ee

\end{document}
```

So far for the LaTeXnical aspects of your question.

**However**, I would like to convince you **not** to use these abbreviations. At the very moment you collaborate with others, this will be extremely cumbersome; everyone comes with their own abbreviations. And in this millennium there is also no need for that, every editor has shortcuts.

Comment: +1 for the last three lines!