# Cannot define a split equation macro

Tags: macros, equations, split

I want to combine the \equation* command and the \split command into a single macro.  This is what I want to do:

```
\def\beqn{\begin{equation*} \begin{split}}
\def\eeqn{\end{split} \end{equation*}}

\beqn
x_1 &=x_0+h\cdot f(t_0,x_0) \\
&=1+(0.1)(2x_0^2+x_0-1) \\
&=1+(0.1)(2+1-1)=1.2
\eeqn
```

But when I compile I get this error:

```
Runaway argument?
x_1 &=x_0+h\cdot f(t_0,x_0) \\ &=1+(0.1)(2x_0^2+x_0-1) \\ &=1+(0.1)(2\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \split was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

The problem seems to be with the \end{split}.  If I write the macro with the \end{split} left out and typed out before \eeqn, it works just fine.  Does anyone know  what's going on here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Your question seems to be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/476411/121799.

Comment: There is also a very similar question of the our moderator Stefan Kottwitz here: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=16272

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for, Sebastiano.  Thank you so much.  The duplicate questions noted above are similar, but I was specifically looking for a way to put both commands into a single macro.  The question linked looks like it does exactly that

Comment: @chloapsoap We're here to help you. Unfortunately on our site, as correctly detected marmot, there is a question very similar to yours. You are welcome and I am happy to have helped you. If you have any questions we are available. My regards.

Comment: Indeed, this question is a duplicate.  But if everything within `equation*` is to be split, the construct is fully equivalent to `align*`, so why not just use that?