Setting textstyle as default with amsmath and align
I am trying to set all math environments to use \textstyle as the default everywhere in my document and trying to follow the solution outlined here: \textstyle as default method of displaying mathematics and Using \textstyle as default with amsmath environments?. Unfortunately, even with a tiny minimal example, it seems to be complaining inside the ams environments like gather and align with the complaint
Improper \halign inside $$'s. 

I've tried various permutations of ordering the key lines:
\let\displaystyle\textstyle
\everydisplay{\textstyle}
\usepackage{amsmath}

but without success. Is this just an ordering issue, or have I misunderstood something?
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, onecolumn]{extarticle}

\let\displaystyle\textstyle
\everydisplay{\textstyle}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a  = b \text{ and }
\sum_{x}^{y} b   = \sup_{c < C} c
\end{equation}
\begin{gather}
a  = b \\
\sum_{x}^{y} b   = \sup_{c < C} c
\end{gather}
\begin{align}
a & = b\\
\sum_{x}^{y} b &  = \sup_{c < C} c
\end{align}
\end{document}

Some difficulties:
So trying to make this work for a fuller fledged range of environments, I am noting some pitfalls: Notably the $$...$$ is a bit problematic, alongside equation*. (A naive attempt at \AtBeginEnvironment{equation*}{\textstyle} hasn't been successful). I've taken or tried some approached from:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37542/106804
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321960/106804
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60395/106804

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, onecolumn]{extarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Makes most (all) math environements use \textstyle 
\let\displaystyle\relax
\let\oldeq\equation
\def\equation{\oldeq\textstyle}

\def\[#1\]{\begin{equation}#1\notag\end{equation}}


\begin{document}
Some inline stuff:  $\sum_{x}^{y} b   = \sup_{c < C} c $ with single \verb|$...$| or \(\sum_{x}^{y} b   = \sup_{c < C} c \) using \verb|\(...\)|

Some display style stuff: with Double \$\$ stuff \$\$
$$\color{red} \sum_{x}^{y} b   = \sup_{c < C} c $$
and then with \verb|\[ stuff \]|
\[\sum_{x}^{y} b   = \sup_{c < C} c\]

Using equation
\begin{equation}
\text{ no star \texttt{equation} }
\sum_{x}^{y} b   = \sup_{c < C} c
\end{equation}
\begin{equation*}
\text{ with star \texttt{equation*} }
\color{red} \sum_{x}^{y} b   = \sup_{c < C} c
\end{equation*}

Using gather and align
\begin{gather}
\sum_{x}^{y} b   = \sup_{c < C} c
\end{gather}
\begin{align}
\sum_{x}^{y} b &  = \sup_{c < C} c
\end{align}
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x}^{y} b &  = \sup_{c < C} c
\end{align*}
\end{document}



\def\[#1\] don't do that! just add it to \[ as you do for equation

@DavidCarlisle - What would that look like?

\let\foo\[ \def\[{\foo\textstyle}

Math alignments depend on a special feature of \halign than while it normally has to be used in vertical mode it is allowed in display math if it is the first item.
So this produces a math alignment in plain tex

$$
%\textstyle
\halign{%
\hfil$#$&$#$\hfil\cr
aaa&bbb\cr
x&y\cr
}
$$

\bye

but if you uncomment the \textstyle (or put any non expandable token there)
then you get the error
! Improper \halign inside $$'s.
l.3 \halign

as alignments use (as in this example) inline math in each cell, and then apply \displaystyle  it would be enough to use \let\displaystyle\relax to avoid getting displaystyle in alignments.
Why do you want this?

So I am not sure I've been able to set \let\displaystyle\relax properly, as if I do just this (without any \everydisplay{\textstyle}), then it works in the second to environments but not the equation environment.
As for "why" I want to do this, mostly as an exercise. Writing an article in two column mode and I am stacking a lot of equations vertically which contains sums or integrals, and I can vertically compress this a fair bit if I use textstyle. Mostly curious to see if I can easy toggle between the two while drafting.

@oliversm sure \[ and equation use display math $$ so those you would have to insert \textstyle (or redefine them to use inline math)  but you should redefine the enviornments not use \everydisplay which is more dispalys than you want

So using the advice from this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37536/106804 my current solution is to use
\let\displaystyle\relax
\let\oldeq\equation
\def\equation{\oldeq\textstyle}

@oliversm yes exactly (and same for \[)

Trying to include \[...\] into the mix has taken me down a small rabbit hole, so I have added some edits to the question to show where I am experiencing some difficulties (fully aware that this is all very ill advisable in the first place).
